# R: glmmADMB error "'x' must be a square numeric matrix"

Tags: r, glm, lme4

What is the syntax in `glmmADMB`?

With `glmer` my code looks like:

```
fit<- glmer(A~B+C+ (1 | D)+ (1 | E), family = gaussian, data=data)
```

how to rewrite the same exact thing using `glmmADMB`?

I was trying:

```
fit<- glmmadmb(A~B+C+ (1 | D)+ (1 | E), family = "gaussian", data=data)
```

but it gives an error:

```
Error in diff(sval) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'diff': Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : 'x' must be a square numeric matrix
```

I get this error even when I'm trying to run the code from the example.

Comment: so are you saying that you get this error with the `bacteria` example from `?glmmadmb`? can you post results of `sessionInfo()` (at least platform/operating system and version of `glmmADMB`, as well as whether you have any other packages loaded)?

Comment: results of `traceback()` (run immediately after you encounter the error) would also be useful.  I don't see `diff(sval)` anywhere in the glmmADMB R code ...

Comment: looking a little bit farther, it seems that this is probably coming from the `rank()` check in `glmmADMB`.  Really do need a reproducible example ...

Comment: `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] glmmADMB_0.8.2 MASS_7.3-43   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Matrix_1.2-2    plyr_1.8.3      magrittr_1.5    tools_3.2.2     coda_0.17-1     Rcpp_0.12.0     stringi_0.5-5   nlme_3.1-121    grid_3.2.2      stringr_1.0.0  
[11] R2admb_0.7.13   lattice_0.20-33 `

Comment: the error appears only in R-studio, but nor in R itself

Comment: And I tried running the example code: `## Australian H. influenzae data from MASS
data(bacteria,package="MASS")
bacteria$present <- as.numeric(bacteria$y)-1
if (!check_rforge())
    (bfit <-  glmmadmb(present ~ trt + I(week > 2), random = ~ 1 | ID,
                       family = "binomial", data = bacteria))` and got that error anyway

Comment: So it works if you run it in R (Rgui or command line) but not from within RStudio? Works for me on MacOS 3.2.2 with similar attached package ...

Comment: Now I'm getting `Error in glmmadmb : The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file) Troubleshooting steps include (1) run with 'save.dir' set and inspect output files; (2) change run parameters: see '?admbControl' In addition: Warning message: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/Users/Liza/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/glmmADMB/bin/windows64/glmmadmb.exe" -maxfn 500 -maxph 5 -noinit -shess' had status 1` I tried troubleshooting, but I can't find what's wrong, here are my .pin and .dat files [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9zghx8k54k6bsx/glmmADMB.zip?dl=0)